# ¿PROBLEMA CON LAS PETICIONES DE CRUD?

Tags: javascript, crud, peticiones

hola buenas tengo un problema he realizado las peticiones del crud de libros que estoy armando pero a la hora de validar errores no me los valida es como si no reconociera la estructura if y la peticion PUT no me funciona he probado de varias formas distintas el codigo y no encuentro solucion lo que intento hacer es que los datos se guarden en un archivo json menos la peticion PUT las otras funcionan todo desde postman desde el navegador surgen algunos inconvenientes tambien desde ya garadezco que alguien me ayude y disculpen las molestias saludos.

```js
const express = require("express");
const api = express.Router();

const { booksController } = require("../controllers");

api.get("/books", booksController.cardBooks);
api.get("/books/new-entry", booksController.formBooks);
api.post("/books/new-book", booksController.createBook);
api.put("/update/:id", booksController.updateBook);
api.delete("/delete/:id", booksController.deleteBook);
api.get("/books/:id", booksController.oneBook);

module.exports = api;
```

el codigo a continuacion es un archivo de controllador vinculado al ruteo!!

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

//** Lee los datos del archivo json permitiendo agregar un nuevo dato sin quitar los que ya estaban **/

const json_books = fs.readFileSync("books.json", "utf-8");
let books = JSON.parse(json_books);

//----------------------------------------------

// Peticiones GET
const cardBooks = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render("index.ejs", {
    books,
  });
};

const formBooks = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render("new-entry.ejs");
};

// Peticion POST
const createBook = (req, res) => {
  const { nombre, descripcion, año, genero, author, url } = req.body;

  if (!nombre || !descripcion || !año || !genero || !author || !url)
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ message: "Debes Completar Todos Los Campos" });

  let newBook = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    nombre,
    descripcion,
    año,
    genero,
    author,
    url,
  };

  books.push(newBook);

  //** Guarda los datos dentro de el archivo json llamdo book.json **/

  const json_books = JSON.stringify(books);
  fs.writeFileSync("books.json", json_books, "utf-8");

  res.status(200).send({ message: "Libro Añadido Exitosamente!" });

  //----------------------------------------------
};

// Peticion PUT
const updateBook = (req, res) => {
  const json_books = JSON.stringify(books);
  fs.writeFileSync("books.json", json_books, "utf-8");

  books = books.filter((books) => books.id === req.params.id);

  res.status(200).send({ message: "Libro Actualizado Exitosamente!" });
};

// Peticion DELETE
const deleteBook = (req, res) => {
  books = books.filter((books) => books.id !== req.params.id);

  const json_books = JSON.stringify(books);
  fs.writeFileSync("books.json", json_books, "utf-8");

  if (!books)
    return res.status(404).send({
      message: "El Libro No Se Encuentra o ya Fue Borrado.",
    });

  res.status(200).send({ message: "Libro Eliminado Exitosamente" });
};

// Peticion GET de un libro
const oneBook = (req, res) => {
  const json_books = fs.readFileSync("books.json", "utf-8");
  let books = JSON.parse(json_books);

  if (!books)
    return res.status(404).send({ message: "El Libro Solicitado No Existe." });

  books = books.filter((books) => books.id === req.params.id);

  res.status(200).render("index.ejs", {
    books,
  });
};

module.exports = {
  cardBooks,
  createBook,
  updateBook,
  deleteBook,
  oneBook,
  formBooks,
};
```

[image: postman peticion PUT status 200 no me reconoce otros status]

Comment: Veo un if para el post, pero no veo ningún if en la función `updateBook`

Comment: hola pablo como estas gracias por responder no esta puesto porque como no me valida los otros no lo puse queria esperar a resolver el problema antes de ponerlo ya que pense que si lo agregaba hiba a tener el mismo resultado el de no funcionar como los otros saludos